# Embedding cells form one table into cells of an existing Word tables at a bookmark with flextable and officer

Tags: r, flextable, officer

In Word, it is possible to copy and paste a subsection of one table into another table. For example, if I have the two Word tables below, I can copy column 2, rows 2-5 from the first table and paste them into column 2, rows 4-7 in the second table.

[image]

I can highlight the cells that I want to copy in the first table and and paste them into the cells of the second table.

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a programmatic way to do a similar operation with `flextable` and `officer`. It's probably worth mentioning the following to parameters:

1. Creating the second table from scratch with the values from the first table included won't work for my problem -- or at least it's a solution that I'm trying to avoid.
2. Adding the values from the first table to the cells of the second table one at a time with bookmarks won't work for my problem -- or at least it's a solution that I'm trying to avoid.

I've tried the following potential solutions so far. They all begin with the following [template Word document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ac06bgempt2kpzz/embedding_flextables_in_existing_word_tables.docx?dl=0) with bookmarks embedded in the table.

Additionally, here is the code I'm using to create the "First table" example data.

```
first_table <- tibble(
  n_items = 1:4,
  n = c(100, 40, 20, 5)
)
```

**Method 1: Add values to a bookmark in the second table**

[image]

Start by reading in the Word template document.

```
doc <- read_docx("embedding_flextables_in_existing_word_tables.docx")
```

Then, I tried adding the *values* from first_table to the bookmark in the second table.

```
doc <- doc %>% 
  body_replace_text_at_bkm(
    "bm_add_rows_01", 
    first_table %>% pull(n) %>% as.character()
  )
```

That code results in the following error:

```
Error in body_replace_text_at_bkm(., "bm_add_rows_01", first_table %>% : 
is_scalar_character(value) is not TRUE
```

So, I can't add a vector of values to the bookmark.

**Method 2: Add a single-column flextable to a bookmark in the second table**

To do this, I need to first coerce first_table into a single-column flextable object.

```
first_table_ft <- first_table %>% 
  select(n) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  delete_part("header") %>% 
  border_remove()
```

Then, add the single-column flextable to the bookmark in the second table.

```
doc <- doc %>% 
  body_replace_flextable_at_bkm("bm_add_rows_01", first_table_ft)
```

```
print(
  doc, 
  "embedding_flextables.docx"
)
```

That returns the following result -- a four-row table embedded into a single cell of the second table. This result makes sense, but it isn't the result I'm attempting to achieve.

[image]

**Method 3: Add a single-column flextable to a bookmark in the second table with cells merged vertically**

For my third attempt, I tried adding the bookmark to the second table with rows 4-7 merged in column 2.

[image]

Then, adding the single-column flextable to the bookmark in the second table as before.

```
doc <- doc %>% 
  body_replace_flextable_at_bkm("bm_add_rows_02", first_table_ft)
```

```
print(
  doc, 
  "embedding_flextables.docx"
)
```

Which again returns a result that isn't quite what I'm looking for.

[image]

Any solutions and/or constructive feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Is there a good reason not to do this by populating the data into a df before passing it to flextable?

Comment: You can have df1 with the table structure and df2 with the data and create a df3 from both?  Or, if you really want to make your life hard, update the flextable values... But you'd have more fun juggling with a hot poker